# How to terminate SQL Dependency when stop debugging?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sqldependency

I am using SQL Dependency in the application. When I stop debugging, SQL Dependency doesn't stop and I got many SqlQueryNotificationService in Queues tab. What event I have to trigger to stop SQL Dependency?

Answer (score 0):

The docs on SQLDepencency say that there is a Stop method (actually two: one each for the two Start methods). You should probably call one of those...